# Docker Toolbox error "can't open file"

Tags: python, docker

I've been struggling to get a Docker image up and running on Windows 10 Home, using Docker Toolbox. Here is the error that I see in Kitematic:

```
python: can't open file 'src/__main__.py': [Errno 2]   
No such file or directory
```

This Python command that is failing is the entry point for the 'notes' Docker container.

After Docker/up.sh the process finishes without any errors.

```
Successfully built f59c275721cf
Successfully tagged docker_mysql:latest
Creating mysql ... done
Creating notes ... done
```

Additionally, this is a group project in which other users on Macs aren't able to duplicate this error. After updating Dockerfile to below and running:

```
Successfully built 42a95cd419f2
Successfully tagged docker_mysql:latest
Creating mysql ... done
Creating notes ... done

User@DESKTOP-EBUI9GE MINGW64 /c/users/user/Desktop/6440/Procedure-Notes-Application (master)
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
68f60fdba6f5        docker_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:23306->3306/tcp   mysql

User@DESKTOP-EBUI9GE MINGW64 /c/users/user/Desktop/6440/Procedure-Notes-Application (master)
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                     NAMES
e7fbd5b73189        docker_notes        "python /app/src/__m…"   23 seconds ago      Exited (2) 17 seconds ago                             notes
68f60fdba6f5        docker_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds               0.0.0.0:23306->3306/tcp   mysql
```

Updated Dockerfile:

```
### Use an official Python runtime as a parent image 
FROM python:2.7-slim

### set working directory to the code location
WORKDIR /app

### copy the code base over (redone by the compose file)
COPY . .

### Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

### Make port available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

### start the application
CMD ["python", "/app/src/__main__.py"]
```

I am now getting another error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/__main__.py", line 57, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: How was the container created? Is it possible you have a `volumes` entry that mounts from a local directory that you don't have, or perhaps bad ADD/WORKDIR in the Dockerfile?

Comment: I have posted the Dockerfile in the edit above

Comment: You don't need `mkdir`, as WORKDIR will create it. It's also better to use absolute references, such as `WORKDIR /app` and `CMD ["python", "/app/src/__main__.py"]`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the same result as before I have edited the post to reflect the results. Looks like the image runs briefly before exiting.

Comment: I'm getting another error, latest edit the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

My first remark, that let the process start was:

> You don't need mkdir, as WORKDIR will create it.
>   It's also better to use absolute references, such as `WORKDIR /app` and
>   `CMD ["python", "/app/src/__main__.py"]`.

The Python script now starts and stops the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

This is typically an error in the Python script. One possibility is described in the post
[python subprocess.call() not working as expected](https://askubuntu.com/a/801496):

> By default `subprocess.call` doesn't use a shell to run our commands
>   you so can't shell commands like `cd`.
>
> To use a shell to run your commands use `shell=True` as parameter. In
>   that case it is recommended to pass your commands as a single string
>   rather than as a list. And as it's run by a shell you can use `~/` in
>   your path, too:
>
> ```
> subprocess.call("(cd ~/catkin_ws/src && catkin_make)", shell=True)
> ```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I realized I was having issues with the volume section in my compose file. After fixing that I added a line in the Dockerfile to give execution permission to main, and it seems to be working after that, but because Volumes wont work I'm having to rebuild every time.